# Стилистическая окраска союза "дабы"

Tags: союзы

Носители языка! Вы используете в современном разговорном языке целевой союз **дабы**? Он стилистически считается книжным словом?

Нашла такой пример: *Не высовывайся, дабы не привлекать внимания.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Не высовывайся, **дабы** не привлекать внимания.

Во текстах XIX такое выражение относилось бы к нейтральному стилю, союз ДАБЫ тогда  использовался наравне с ЧТОБЫ и не имел стилистической окраски. Например: На другой день Алексей, твёрдый в своём намерении, рано утром поехал к Муромскому, дабы (чтобы) откровенно с ним объясниться (А. С. Пушкин).

Но в современной речи союз ДАБЫ уже не является синонимом нейтрального союза ЧТОБЫ. "Дабы" может использоваться в художественной и публицистической речи, но он, как мне кажется, **всегда ироничен и  является скорее пародией на высокий (книжный) стиль.**

В публицистике при описании обыденных ситуаций он приписывает им  нечто возвышенное, например: "В Сибирь приехали учёные люди из Оксфорда, **дабы** просветить омичей на предмет избавления от мусора". "В это время Владимир сменил фамилию на Пролетарский, **дабы** подчеркнуть свое происхождение и преданность делу революции".

**Да и в современных романах при наличии союза ДАБЫ ирония всегда присутствует, хотя и не такая откровенная:** "Но Саша имел привычку ничего лишнего не знать, не выпытывать, **дабы** не носить в голове информацию, которую можно было бы извлечь тем или иным, вполне кустарным способом. [Захар Прилепин).

Answer (score 1):

ДАБЫ - устаревшее слово (даже в словаре Ушакова с пометой *устар., книжн.*),  современный аналог - ЧТОБЫ.

Comment: KseniaK, Здесь не принято здороваться и передавать приветы. Даже благодарности весьма ограничены форматом ресурса. Лучшая вежливость - краткость, точность и содержательность ваших текстов.

Comment: Но здесь еще и другая беда. Автор не спрашивает о нормативности слова, он интересуется личным  словарным запасом читающего, а это "опрос", т. е. вопрос, ответ на который субъективен по своей сути. С такими - в Левада-центр. )))

Answer (score 0):

Что касается вашего примера, то во втором лице и ввиду императивной тональности предложения он воспринимается плохо, во всяком случае, с позиций трактовки современной речи. Для меня "дабы" нормально звучит в применении к третьему лицу и прошедшему времени (как во всех уже приведённых литературных примерах). В современных ситуациях применение подзабытого "дабы" может быть обусловлено желанием говорящего (пишущего) разнообразить или приукрасить свою речь, либо придать выражению оттенок фамильярности, доверительности, иронии и т. п., отличный от возникающего при использовании нейтрального "чтобы". В некоторых случаях современного употребления "дабы" может восприниматься даже как доверительное "ясное дело - чтобы", в то время как простое "чтобы" лишь указывает на причину чьего-то действия, не всегда убедительную.